# ui-router keep controller active

Tags: android, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an app, and I would love to keep the config of a user shown on screen when it goes to the settings back and forward.

The my routes are configured as following:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Initialize the router's default behaviors
 */
// @ngInject
function initRouter($urlRouterProvider: angular.ui.IUrlRouterProvider,
                    $stateProvider: angular.ui.IStateProvider): void {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: '/angular/app/components/_header/headerView.html'
                },
                'sidebar': {
                    templateUrl: '/angular/app/components/_sidebar/sidebarView.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/main',
            views: {
                'main@': {
                    templateUrl: '/angular/app/components/landing/landingView.html',
                    controller: 'LandingController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.settings', { 
        url: '/config',
        views: {
            'main@': {
                templateUrl: '/angular/app/components/settings/settingsView.html',
                controller: 'settingsController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    });
}

angular.module('app').config(initRouter);
```

So if I go from `app.home` type something in an input field then go to `app.settings` and then back to `app.home` I would love to still see that same thing in my input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to put it in the controller. create a service and put this information there, and access it through a callback. Services are not reset or destroyed, but controllers are.